# Where am I going wrong with getStaticProps() and getStaticPaths()?

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, dynamic-routing

#### The Issue

I cannot query the API by slug, it must be by id. An `KeystoneJS headless CMS` provide the data via API and my NextJS should use this data in a static generated Next.js app.
Keystone API must be queried like this:

All Posts: `(ALL_POSTS_QUERY)`

```js
query {
  allPosts {
    id
    slug
    title
  }
}
```

Single Post: `(POST_QUERY)`

```
query {
  Post(where: { id: $id }) {
   title
   body
  }
}
```

I do use `Apollo Client` to connect to the API endpoint.

A query for an individual post must be formatted as described above, with an id variable and that's what seems to be the issue. I need to generate static pages by **slug** and not by id.

#### The functions

`getStaticPaths()`

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: ALL_POSTS_QUERY,
  });

  return {
    paths: data.allPosts.map(({ id, slug }) => ({
      params: { slug: slug },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

`getStaticProps()`

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const id = params.id;
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: POST_QUERY,
    variables: {
      id,
    },
  });
  return {
    props: {
      term: data.Post,
    },
  };
};
```

More info about [KeystoneJS generated APIs](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/intro-to-graphql).

#### Please help

I'm very new to developing so my understanding of this is still basic. Apologies if I've misunderstood the logic. Please can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong with my functions? I wasn't able to find anyone else trying to build dynamic routes by slug but querying the API by id to retrieve that post's data.

Comment: The main question: What are the querystring from your nextJS pages.
Means, how does the URI - which opens the nextjs-page - looks like? Is it like `mydomain.com/bimbom/123` or like `mydomain.com/bimbom?id=123` or something else? 
Please give more details about what it should looks like.

Comment: It's like the first one: mydomain.com/posts/slug

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you want to access the prop `id` of `params`, but `params.id` simply does not exist. What exists is `params.slug`. If you want to pass through the `id`, then change your code to this:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: ALL_POSTS_QUERY,
  });

  return {
    paths: data.allPosts.map(({ id, slug }) => ({
      params: { id },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

Now you are passing through the `id` instead of the `slug` and should be fine.

Comment: That doesn't tell Next to create static paths for slug though? It will build paths by ID?

Comment: You can name the slug however you want. It is just the name of the variable.

Comment: But I get `Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /posts/[slug]`, so I must pass `slug` but I need to fetch the data by passing the ID...

Comment: What is the name of the file and the full path of it? Also read more here about it: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

Comment: I've read the documentation numerous times and still unable to find a way of building pages by slug but fetching the data by ID. It might not be possible it seems.